# Which part of the source code should I lock?

Tags: c#, tcp, thread-safety, locking

The following are the basic skeleton of my .net server:

### [C# server skeleton](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15_AscdIh-EBmZzbLiIc0MyrAvMZGFtQE)

```
class ServerProgram
{
    static string origClientID = string.Empty;
    static string reqClientID = string.Empty;
    static string stKey = string.Empty;
    static string stValue = string.Empty;
    static Dictionary<string, KeyValue> KeyValueDictionary;
    static Dictionary<string, ClientClass> ClientDictionary;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Server";
        Console.WriteLine("Server program started on address [" + Constants.SERVER_IP +":"+Constants.PORT_NO+"]");

        KeyValueDictionary = new Dictionary<string, KeyValue>();
        ClientDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ClientClass>();

        string ipAddress = Constants.SERVER_IP;
        int portNo = Constants.PORT_NO;

        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);            
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, portNo);            

        // poll for clients in a 2nd thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            ServerProgram.PollIncomingClientConns(listener);
        });

        thread.Start();
    }

    #region catching client connections
    static void PollIncomingClientConns(TcpListener listener)
    {
        listener.Start();

        try
        {
            bool keepRunning = true;

            while (keepRunning)
            {
                ClientClass client = new ClientClass(listener);

                ClientDictionary.Add(client.ID, client);

                Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    ServerProgram.ReadFromClient(client);
                });
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var inner = ex.InnerException as SocketException;
            if (inner != null && inner.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            listener.Stop();
        }
    } 
    #endregion     

    static void ReadFromClient(ClientClass client)
    {
       try
        {
            while (client.Tcp.Connected)
            {
                string str = client.Read();
                Console.WriteLine("[" + client.ID + "] says: " + str);

                switch(str)
                {
                    case Commands.AddKeyValue:
                        //...                        
                        break;

                    case Commands.ListKeys:
                        //...
                        break;

                    case Commands.UpdateValue: 
                        //...
                        break;

                    case Commands.Yes:                            
                        //...
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

The objective of the program is:

1. the server keeps a common dictionary of key-values.
2. clients are able to add, update, and see the key-values in the server.

There are six static global variables used in the class.

Which of them should I lock before accessing (I think, dictionaries do not need locking)?

Which part of code should I lock?  Should I lock switch-cases individually, or, should I lock the entire while loop in `static void ReadFromClient(ClientClass client)`?

Comment: side note: "thread per client" is usually not a great idea in anything except trivial servers with very few clients

Comment: additional side note: you never remove from `ClientDictionary` - that sounds like a problem to me

Comment: @MarcGravell, `additional side note: you never remove from ClientDictionary - that sounds like a problem to me` -- that is not a part of my requirement.

Comment: "that is not a part of my requirement" - so... you just want to grow a dictionary indefinitely...?

Comment: @MarcGravell, this how my teacher wants things to happen.

Comment: then I suggest you go and ask your teacher your questions, but no real-life scenario would be done this way...

Comment: @MarcGravell, I asked.

Answer (score 2):

We can *definitely* say that you should be synchronizing access of the two dictionaries - since no operations on dictionaries are documented as being thread-safe, and you're mutating them from multiple threads. Some similar structures *do* have thread-safety notes, but not `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Whether you need to synchronize the strings is ... tricky, not least because you don't show the usage. Reads and writes against reference-types (`string`) are atomic, and strings themselves are immutable (at least when used normally). However, if you are doing multiple operations that would assume an unchanged value between them, you may need to synchronize for the duration of *composite* operations. Additionally, keep in mind that you can't just `lock (stValue)`, because when `stValue` changes, two different paths will be locking against **different objects**. Instead, you'd need a separate field that exists *just for locking*, and is independent of the value.

Finally, note that `static` fields - when mutable like this - are often a bad idea.

Comment: Where in the OP's posted code is it accessing `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` objects from different threads at the same time?

Comment: @Neijwiert I think we can reasonably assume from the flavor of the code that this server is meant to have multiple concurrent clients; if not, then that's a much bigger problem than everything else in the code :)

Comment: I agree with that, but the administration of clients is only done in the polling thread. Which is, so far, thread safe.

Comment: @Neijwiert the fact that the listen loop is the thing that *adds* them to the dictionary doesn't tell us much; the "remove" isn't shown, and the only sensible place that could be added (and it *must* be added, to avoid a leak) is at the end of the per-thread read loop, so... again: I think we can reasonable assume that it is going to need synchronization; you are right that I didn't make this explicit, however!

Comment: Your answer is very abstract. I failed to understand.

Comment: @user366312 locking isn't as simple as "do this" - it depends on *what you're doing*, which you aren't showing - hence abstract is the best I can offer